# What's the quickest way to send lots of data over BLE?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

If I want to transfer a lot of data (e.g. 1 MB file) over BLE, what's the best way to do it?

I control both sides of the connection, but the client side is iOS/Android so only has access to GATT. I can't do anything with L2CAP.

I also can't wait for Bluetooth 4.1, 6LoWPAN, Connection-Oriented-Channels or anything like that.

I would assume the answer is to have one "request" characteristic that you write a data request to ("Give me 3000 bytes starting at byte 0"), and a "data out" characteristic that sends lots of 20 byte notifications (the maximum characteristic size) containing the data.

Is there a better way?

Comment: From peripheral to central or central to peripheral?

Comment: Oops forgot to say: peripheral to central.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we are using the approach you have mentioned.

1. Request data with the last index number(First time the index is 0)
2. The server send you with data with index no.Store the index no for subsequent format
3. continue Step 1 and 2 till the time server sends end of data-probably with index -1 or something.

Make sure you transfer the data you required in the most space efficient format.See if you can zip the files and transfer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can update connection interval to small value with smallest 6*1.25 ms in remote BLE device.

Actually, BLE is designed for Low energy, small packet, low data rate.
L2cap data will be transmitted in different data channel with frequency hop. Packets TX/RX happen within each connection interval and max number of packets TX/RX in an event is restricted by specification, finally implemented by manufacture. So we can change connection interval as small as possible to increase data rate.

Refer BT 4.0 spec Vol 2, 7.8.18 LE Connection Update Command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to negotiate a larger MTU than the default.
Then each notification can be larger. Even though it will be fragmented by the L2CAP layer, you will get a slightly larger throughput since the packet header will be smaller.